# How to enforce google-cloud-bigquery==0.28.0 installation on the dataflow workers

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am having very hard time to get the latest version of bigquery working on dataflow workers.
Can someone advice what will be the easier way to make this work.
Having setup.py with google-cloud-bigquery==0.28.0 will fail the installtion of the workflow on the workers-startup time.

As you can see from this link: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/python-client-migration
the google-cloud-bigquery 0.25.0 that is latest version that is currently supported on dataflow is very cumbersome and not efficient.
Please let me know if you have any advice.

Many thanks,
eilalan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment. This should be fixed by Beam 2.7.0.

In the meantime - keep using google-cloud-bigquery 0.25.0 - Beam 2.7.0 should be out in a few weeks.

Comment: how can we see the latest versions of google-cloud-bigquery that Beam 2.8.0 is compatible with?